# java-private inner class instances not getting garbage collected

Tags: java, javafx, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I know questions regarding memory leak for non-static inner classes have already been asked before. I read questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864853/when-exactly-is-it-leak-safe-to-use-anonymous-inner-classes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429121/are-non-static-inner-class-objects-garbage-collected-after-they-are-no-longer-re) but I don't fully understand what wrong am I doing.

My class is as below

```
    public class AddNewProductDialog {
        private static AddNewProductDialog dialog;
        private TextInputDialog newProductName = new TextInputDialog();

        private AddNewProductDialog(){
        }

        public static AddNewProductDialog getInstance(){
            if(dialog == null){
                dialog = new AddNewProductDialog();
            }
            return dialog;
        }

        /*Helper Class start*/
        private class AddNewProductDialogHelper{

            private void initializeDialog(){ //---> Prepare a dialog box
                newProductName.setTitle("Add New Product");
                newProductName.setHeaderText("Note: This product name will be used as bat script file name. Eg. call_<productname>_script");
                newProductName.setContentText("Product Name :");
                newProductName.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).setDisable(true);

/*Something over here*/
                newProductName.getEditor().textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(isInputvalid(newProductName.getEditor().getText())){
                            newProductName.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).setDisable(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            private boolean isInputvalid(String text){
                if(text.trim().length() > 0)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }

        }
        /*Helper class end*/

        public AddNewProductDialog build(){
            new AddNewProductDialogHelper().initializeDialog();
            return this;
        }

        public void show() {
            Optional<String> result = newProductName.showAndWait();
            if(result.isPresent()){
                //----> handle the input
            }
        }
    }
```

The `AddNewProductDialog` (outer) class is a singleton class which has a helper class `AddNewProductDialogHelper`. This helper class sets the properties of `TextInputDialog newProductName`

I am calling the `build` method of class `AddNewProductDialog` followed by `show` method as `AddNewProductDialog.getInstance().build().show()` **everytime a button is clicked** to take user input.

I want the instance of the `AddNewProductDialogHelper` to be garbage collected after it is done initializing `newProductName` `dialog box`

The **problem** is that, the instances of `AddNewProductDialogHelper` are pilling up in Heap memory and are not getting garbage collected. Everytime I click the button to get user input a new instance is getting created and it keeps on pilling up as the button is clicked

**However**, when I comment this code block

```
newProductName.getEditor().textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(isInputvalid(newProductName.getEditor().getText())){
                        newProductName.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).setDisable(false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

**it works** and previous instances ***are*** getting garbage collected. **Why does commenting this code block works?**

I am using [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) to check my **heap dump**

Comment: `isInputValid` is a method of your helper and is then in the closure of the listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding those inner objects as listeners to a listener list.

Thus there is a reference kept to them.

So I think the problem is not in the section that you claim to cause trouble, but the line above. As long as you don't somehow remove the inner objects from that listener list they can't be garbage collected.

So the solution is probably complicated: you should step back and change your approach... You need to be able to remember these inner objects so that you can unregister them at some point.

And beyond that: strange design. Also looks hard to test for me.

Comment: Thanks for our reply. Would appreciate you help in deciding the right design approach.

Comment: Sorry, a) I am on my mobile and b) that would require many many exchanges about your requirements and the problem you try to solve... And that is not what this community is about. We help with programming problems not with framing your whole application.

Comment: @Nishant123 When the problem is solved, then [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java) may be the right site for you.

Comment: @maaartinus Thank you!!